# Android Native Functions

Tags: android, select, webview, highlight, gesture

I'm trying to create an active reading application prototype for my course project in Android platform. I'm new to Android SDK, and I cannot figure out how to use WebView's native functions, because I need to use them to implement selecting / highlighting / copying texts using gestures. I saw that WebView has a function setSelection but it's private and I cannot use it.

But I think may be there is something that I miss. May be I need to use something else. Please, give me some suggestion, links, books where I can find useful information.